# Firebase not using last bundle.js - React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, bundle, firebase-hosting

I have this boilerplate code from a React course which used Heroku hosting and yarn for development.
I'm switching to Firebase, and I can get my web app up and running but it uses an old build when I deploy (firebase deploy) and run it locally (firebase serve). I guess it has something to do with not picking up the latest bundle.js (and webpack config). 
But tried using build and it won't work. Any ideas on what I should try?

Here's my package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
      "build:dev": "webpack",
      "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
      "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --watch",
      "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config=jest.config.json",
      "start": "node server/server.js",
      "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build:prod"
    },
```

And here's my webpack config:

```
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
      require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.test' });
    } else if  (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development' });
    }


    module.exports = (env) => {
      const isProduction = env === 'production';
      const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

      return {
        entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js'],
        output: {
        path: __dirname+ '/public',
        publicPath: '/public/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
    ...
```

...and continues with modules and plugins. Let me know if there's something else I can add to make it more clear.

Thanks in advance!

edit: Adding firebase.json default config

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "public/dist/bundle.js"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Firebase keys should be hardcoded into the firebase.js file. 
Firebase hosting only supports static sites so you need to make sure everything is already bundled before uploading it.
Hope it helps someone in the future!